# How was this question with a previously upvoted and accepted answer deleted?

Tags: support, deletion

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73116417/7519434) and my answer was upvoted and accepted but the question has since been deleted.

The message on the deleted post says "This post is hidden. It was deleted ... by the post author.", but the help centre page on deletion says

> You can't delete your own question if one or more of the following is
> true:
>
> - It has an answer with one or more upvotes (regardless of the answer's
>   net score)
> - It has multiple answers (even if they have no upvotes)
> - It has an accepted answer
> - It has an answer (that isn't deleted) with an awarded bounty
> - Another question has been closed as a duplicate of it

How was this question deleted by the post author if my answer met the above criteria?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood something, the section I've quoted from the help centre means that the question could not have been deleted by the post author?

Comment: And that same user no longer exists, strange. Did they delete and then abscond to avoid being charged with academic plagiarism?

Comment: i think the user delete all questions and then removed himself from the side

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both the upvotes and the accept on your answer had been retracted, leaving your answer at a score of 0 with no accept, which gave way for the asker to be able to delete their question.

You can verify this in your reputation history, where the votes are listed as undos rather than the usual removed text:

[image: Undo actions in reputation history]

Comment: But... there "It *has multiple answers* (even if they have no upvotes)"? Are you sure user actually deleted the post rather than it was deleted as part of user's deletion (also I think in that case posts are deleted by "community")?

Comment: @Alexei The other two answers were already self-deleted by their owners. There was only the one answer at the time.